# Writing each I frame into a different .mp4 file and adding some additional logs

Tags: encoder, x264

While using x264 encoder, how to store each and every I frame (from each and every .png file (frame)) into a different .mp4 file?

If I have 5 frames, after encoding those 5 frames into 5 I frames how to write those in different files?

Another Question: How to put few additional log messages or print statements in few functions in x264 code which I can view on the terminal as the encoding output like other logs???

Comment: Why do you have to encode all 5 frames at once?  If you encode just 1 frame, and save the video, it can only have 1 frame (by definition).  Just do that process 5 times.

Comment: suppose I want to repeat the same thing for 25k frames. Then it's not a feasible solution. I just give one small example. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: I don't know if this would change my answer or not, but why do you want single frame videos when png is already good at that?

Comment: 4K resolution frame (.png) size way much larger than an encoded I frame. Thats why

Comment: Would another compression algorithm, such as JPEG meet your needs?  It seems like you're really trying to convert still images to still images, so it seems reasonable to look at formats that are designed to work with still images.  MP4 is going to be less efficient because it's designed to be better at storing many related frames.